# Storage of symmetric keys in Golang

Tags: key, encryption-symmetric, key-storage

I am currently developing an application which uses symmetric key encryption, with the key generated from an user provided password. I want to include a way for the user to log-in to the application, so for that I need to store the key somewhere accessible by different processes. I am currently using a temporary file for beta testing, but I know that is not very secure. What will be a simple key storage solution in golang?

Comment: There is none. The file is fine provided it's created with `0600` perms (and under a strict `umask`). Also you should consider the key lifetime. If the key is to live only for as long as the running set of apps is active, you can employ a trick of deleting the file while having it open and transferring its file handle to other processes via Unix-domain sockets. This way the file will never be readable by other processes via the filesystem. It will still be readable by whoever possesses the credentials which the processes use and can log into the same machine they are running on.

Comment: I want the key to live for the time user uses the application, which is currently a cli, and therefore will be run as many different processes. The app currently has a logout command to remove the file.

Comment: „as many different processes”—meaning that you run `cli do this`, then it finishes and you run `cli do that`—so there's time spans when there's no active process using the key, right? If yes, a file is okay. You can try to use the "keyring" provided by the OS—such as [GNOME Keyring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Keyring) or Windows Credential Manager. There's no standard cross-platfom solution though.

Comment: I will then keep using the file with the permissions you suggested. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Sensitive information, such as keys, should not be stored in your program/executable as this leaves them vulnerable. You can store the keys outside of your program using a database (where they should not be stored in plain-text) or by using a config file that can be read by your program. You can read more about it on [this](https://groups.google.com/g/Golang-nuts/c/X7ADUV3mRYU) google forum.

Comment: I actually am not storing it inside the exe. My question is, how to keep the key safe externally.

Comment: It was not clear from your question that you are storing it outside of the executable. But as I said in my post, you can store the key externally using a database or a config file. For more information you can see the post that I shared.